# Link react-native peer dependencies

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

I am working on a react-native library `my-library` that has a dependency on `react-native-svg`. This dependency needs to be linked to the main project in order to work.

When a user install my library `npm install my-library --save` and runs `react-native link`, it doesn't link `react-native-svg` to the main project by default.

How can I configure my project so it will link `react-native-svg` to their project when they run `react-native link`?

My current package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js",
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-svg": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can try by adding `postinstall` in package.json

Comment: As much as I wish, I can't really assume the user has react-native-cli installed on their machine.